# Why I can't set value from the database but hard coded values works fine?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using this code to set cellvalue from database but it does not work.

```
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2 = $excel2->load("test.xlsx"); // Empty Sheet


$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Date');

$m=2;
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from settings");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $chan=$row['channelID'];
            $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C$m", $chan);
echo $chan;
echo "<br>";
$m++;
}
```

But when I change this line to static text it works fine

```
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C$m", "static text");
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong I want to set value from the database any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did `echo $chan;` show you? Also, use `print_r($row);` in the loop.

Comment: it shows the values which I have in  the database.

Comment: try to wrap `$chan` in quotes

Comment: Try something like this `$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C$m",''.$chan);`  single quote make it string.

Comment: does not work either.

Comment: how many rows are u retrieving from the db?

Comment: 1819-1 2021 2021-5 1819-1 1819-1
I am retrieving these 5 values from db.

Comment: Where are you saving the changes?

Comment: It works fine now applied trim function before setcellvalue function.